# Custom Eclipse (CDT) project layout, different from folder structure

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

A good hello to you fellow Stackoverflow people.

I am stuck with a small dilemma here.

At my work we used to work with UltraEdit projects but we want to migrate to using Eclipse CDT. (Not using its compiler/build options, we need an external SDK for this).

On the harddisk we have a specific folder structure to keep things seperate between two teams. Namely the 'productcode' + 'applicationcode'-group and the 'drivercode'-group.
Both groups have their own folder where they place sourcecode in.

- application
- drivercode
- productcode

The filenames are given a specific prefix, denoting to which 'layer' they belong.

- os (operating system)
- application
- system
- unit
- component
- IO
- hardware

All of these files (except for application which is only allowed in the application folder) can be in the product or drivercode folder.
In UltraEdit all of these files are grouped under their respective layer. So our project has the following folders:

- 0 Operating System
- 1 Application Layer
- 2 System Safety Layer
- 3 Unit Layer
- 4 Component Layer
- 5 IO Layer
- 6 Hardware Layer
- Generic
- XML

The virtual folder '0 Operating System' holds all os_xxx files from the real folders 'drivercode/productcode' And the same goes for 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

**TL;DR**:
Is it possible to get the same (virtual) folder structure within Eclipse CDT?

To make things more complex, this whole folder structure is devided in 3 projects. E.G. proj-1, proj-2, proj-3 and there is also a shared folder that holds code that is shared among projects.

Comment: You can add files/folders to an Eclipse CDT project without copying them to the workspace (the Import wizard gives you a choice), so you should be able to create projects from them in-place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one way, but it is quite cumbersome.

I can create the structure I want using Linked Resource Folder and files.

However this means I need to go through all dialog's per folder/file in order to add them to the list. I hope there is an other way though. So I'll not accept my own answer as of yet.

Comment: Although I answered and accepted my own question it was not the solution I was looking for. We thought it over and decided to 'just use' the folder structure provided by windows and not use a custom folder structure in the IDE

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation.  Rather than a bunch of hunt/peck for linked resources, which tend break the ability to reuse the .*project files elsewhere, I made a 'workspace setup" script that just symlinked the sources into the directories where their projects were.  That way the default eclipse mechanisms (build all source within a tree) just work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT plays well with existing projects.

I guess you probably also have manually generated Makefile? Then you only need to use File -> Import -> C/C++ -> Existing code as Makefile Project.

This will leave all your source where it was and team members that prefer to no use Eclipse can still use whatever they want, and build from command line.

Comment: Sadly no, we are using the Softune IDE/compiler by fujitsu. For this compiler there is no makefile, you pust add files manually to the project. And it even doesn't depend on where they are located. They will just appear in a flat list. :-(